# Loadrunner Design Studio misses URL encoded variations of correlated parameters

Tags: correlation, loadrunner, vugen

We are a shop that uses LoadRunner and VuGen (recording in standard HTTP/HTML web mode), and have an issue where we have an application which uses long base64 parameters, where in some cases they are encoded (primarily with + turned into %2B), and some are not.  Design studio finds only one or the other (depending on the server response), and correlates requests only using the source encoding, but not both.

For example, let's say that there's a value which needs to be passed back into the application. In the original response from the server which is the source of the correlation, the value is "ABCDEF+012345".

Now, in some cases it is submitted exactly like that, in which case Design Studio successfully correlates the server response and replaces the requests. However, in other cases it's submitted as "ABCDEF%2B012345" (URL encoded to replace + with %2B), in which case Design Studio does NOT correlate the requests which use that variation of the value.

Now it's not a big deal if it's only a single instance to manually add a conversion function, then search/replace the use of the parameters that did not get correlated.  Unfortunately this is cumbersome and we have scripts that have about 100 parameters which are 200-400 characters long. So not only would it take a lot of time to fix this, but since they wrap in the editor frequently due to their length, search/replace isn't possible anyway.

Is there any way to have Design Studio correlate parameters when the used value may or may not be encoded? This seems like it should be a pretty common thing to do.

Comment: ".... but since they wrap in the editor frequently due to their length, search/replace isn't possible anyway...."   Not a cogent argument as people have been doing this manually for close to 20 years with far more parameters than 100 in a script.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using TruClient protocol which solved all of the correlations issues.
If you insist on using HTTP protocol, in your case you rather not use the design studio. Get the parameter yourself using `lr_reg_save_param` command above the code line that calls the HTTP page.
This way, you can specify the left and right bounds yourself and not let the design studio use regex or other recognition methods that are sometimes problematic:

```
lr_reg_save_param("param1", "LB=textleftofyourparam", "RB=textrightofyourparam", LAST);
```